# Cookie Stealer/Login System (PHP)

Tags: php, session, authentication

I've been googling this for some hours but everyone handles it in a different way.

So I'm wondering how to handle the informations when someone logs in.

I thought that I'll save the user ID, name and user-agent-data in the session. But what if someone steals the cookie content and replaces his own cookie with the stolen one?

And yeah, that's actually my question. How can I "protect" the user? Checking the IP as well? Anything else?

Thanks, 
Albin.

Comment: Just making sure I know exactly what you're asking, you are looking for ways to prevent session hijacking from apps like FireSheep, FaceNiff, and the like? Or am I being too specific?

Comment: You're being too specific.. I was thinking about a protection against cookie stealer in general

Answer (score 4):

Not to have a session id or cookies in general stolen is a task the browser has to handle. There are some conceptual means to prevent 3rd parties to learn the contents of your cookies like the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can help the browser by setting the http-only flag for cookies. See the argument $httponly for [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). If a cookie is marked as http-only, the browser will not make it accessable for scripts like javascript. The cookie will only be transferred in the original http-header. this will practically eliminate the risk of XSS-based session capturing, as they usually use javascript.

Another big attack is the [man in the middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). An attacker has access to the traffic between your client and your server. He now can read the http headers, therefore the cookies and imitate the request. He could even spoof your client's IP address. To protect against this kind of attacker, you will need an encrypted connection. Most websites use [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) for this purpose.

If you only need authentication, you can also use [HTTP's digest authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication). There is a working example for digest auth using PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).

Answer (score 0):

Testing if the IP stays the same would be one way. However it's better to test wether it matches a given subnet mask (e.g. `255.255.0.0`), because some users might have dynamical IPs.

Another "protection" measurement is testing wether the user agent of the browser is the same that was used to log in, but of course that's pretty easy to bypass.

Make sure you set the cookies only for your domain or subdomain, and also make sure to check your code not to allow any [XSS flaws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), as these often can be used to steal cookies.

Comment: So, there's actually no other way? I was thinking about a cookie that changes for every request you make and this hash will be saved in the database. But the problem is: what if the user has 2 tabs/windows open? Sucks.

Comment: There might be other ways as well. The one you mention isn't really one of them: An attacker could also steal the cookie containing the hash and then send his request. This would prevent the original user from making further requests, but not the attacker.

Comment: Yeah but the attacker wouldn't have that much time to get that done.

Comment: The attacker could simply prevent the original request. This is commonly done with online bank transfers and TANs.

Comment: Assuming that possible attackers might not be quick enough is a **really** bad way of implementing reliable security. Plus, your session cookies are surely valid for minutes or hours. Therefore an attacker has more than enough time where people currently are not actively browsing the page.